# Proving $μ_F(E) = \int_E F' dλ + μ_F(E∩K)$

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification, cantor-set

The following is an exercise from Bruckner's Real Analysis:

> Let $F$ be the Cantor function. Show that, for every Borel set $E$, $μ_F(E) = \int_E F' dλ + μ_F(E∩K)$, where $K$ is the Cantor ternary set.

I have an answer in mind for this but it looks too simple and non-rigorous to be true! :

$\int_E F' dλ = \int_{E \setminus K} F' dλ = 0$ because $λ(K)=0$ and $F'=0$ on $E \setminus K$. $μ_F(E) = μ_F(E \setminus K) + μ_F(E∩K) = 0 + μ_F(E∩K)$ then just replace $0$ by $\int_E F' dλ$ because it is zero too. Am I right?

Comment: As simple as that since $F’=0$ lebesgue almost surely.

Comment: @OliverDiaz, I feel that what I wrote as a "proof" is not true or at least a rigorous one!

Comment: It is a (rigorous) one liner once you know that $A\mapsto \int_Af\,d\mu$ is the $0$ measure when $f=0$ $\mu$-a.s. which  is likely an exercise that you already worked on.

Comment: Also, $F$ is constant on $K^c$, so $\mu_F(B\cap K^c)=0$.

Comment: @OliverDiaz, OK, thanks a lot :)